# How does multi-device offline-first database sync work with iOS/Android from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, multiple-databases

I've reinvented the wheel (because nobody has yet created this wheel) and created:

- Offline-first which syncs with other users over server
- Multi-user sync secured offline and online databases with hybrid encryption (this sends and recieves new writes only, except for new user which recieves entire database)
- This included handling offline authentication

So it has dawned on me that I have yet another architectural issue here. I've got everything all synced up across multi-users but how do I have one user sync with a new device?

The reason this is an issue is because local users hash credentials are stored on local device for offline authentication. Private asymmetric key is also stored securely on local device. So, if an existing user logs into new device, the login succeeds as long as there is internet access. But immediately there are errors because there is no data locally. Since keys can't be sent over the wire, theres a conundrum.

I can imagine solving this like so:

If remote login succeeds but there is no local data then user would be newly setup locally on new device. Problem is, master remote database which should handle this has encrypted data. This would require a whole bunch of back and forth passing public keys and re-encryption of entire master db with new acls. Seems like a lot of work and requiring both devices in hand...

Apple does this for all their devices and content. How can we?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I imagine Apple protects the private key with the user's Apple ID password. If so, perhaps they are sending the key over the wire. Otherwise, you could research how Signal handles the situation, though I think they do require a primary device to "bless" any new synched devices. One way or another, I don't think it can be both relatively secure & basically transparent to the user.

Comment: Your help gave me an entry point to this (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246598/signal-messaging-app-how-does-sync-on-connected-devices-work)[here] so looks like theres no easy way to do this.